Palo Alto SSL syslog to LimaCharlie adapter gives error: "conn.Read(): read tcp 10.166.0.29:6514->82.164.196.77:21945: read: connection reset by peer"
I have the following setup:
Palo Alto Firewall -> 
Syslog SSL to x.mydomain.com port 6514 ->  
Compute Engine Instance with Ubuntu LTS running i Google Cloud with LimaCharlie Adapter ->  
LimaCharlie.io
I have managed to send syslog from Palo Alto to the compute engine with TCP, but when I send it with SSL I get "connection reset by peer".
TCP Unencrypted - working
I managed to send syslog to the Compute Engine Instance with TCP (unencrypted) on port 6514 with the following command:
cd /opt/limacharlie_adapter/
./lc_adapter syslog client_options.identity.installation_key=f-g-h-i-j client_options.identity.oid=a-b-c-d-e client_options.platform=text client_options.hostname=fw-pa client_options.sensor_seed_key=fw-pa port=6514 iface=0.0.0.0 is_udp=false

SSL Encrypted - not woring
I start the LimaCharlie Adapter with SSL Cert and SSL Key:
cd /opt/limacharlie_adapter/
./lc_adapter syslog client_options.identity.installation_key=f-g-h-i-j client_options.identity.oid=a-b-c-d-e client_options.platform=text client_options.hostname=fw-pa client_options.sensor_seed_key=fw-pa port=6514 iface=0.0.0.0 is_udp=false ssl_cert=/opt/cert/mydomain_com_crt.pem ssl_key=/opt/cert/mydomain_com_rsa_pkcs_1_key.pem

Then I get the follwing error:
Configs in use (syslog):
----------------------------------
client_options:
  identity:
    oid: a-b-c-d-e
    installation_key: f-g-h-i-j
  hostname: fw-pa
  platform: text
  architecture: usp_adapter
  buffer_options: {}
  sensor_seed_key: fw-pa
port: 6514
iface: 0.0.0.0
ssl_cert: /opt/cert/mydomain_com_crt.pem
ssl_key: /opt/cert/mydomain_com_rsa_pkcs_1_key.pem
----------------------------------
 
DBG Jun 20 10:52:34: usp-client connecting
DBG Jun 20 10:52:34: usp-client connected
DBG Jun 20 10:52:34: listening for connections on 0.0.0.0:6514
DBG Jun 20 10:52:35: handling new connection from 82.164.196.77:10208
DBG Jun 20 10:52:37: handling new connection from 82.164.196.77:21945
WRN Jun 20 10:52:37: conn.Read(): read tcp 10.166.0.29:6514->82.164.196.77:21945: read: connection reset by peer
DBG Jun 20 10:52:37: connection from 82.164.196.77:21945 leaving

SSL test message
I also tried to send a test message like this:
bryan@adams:~$ echo "I was in London" | openssl s_client -connect x.mydomain.com:6514

And that message went through with no errors.
What can I do to debug this issue?

Palo alto? Contact the vendor support and let help you

Yes, Palo Alto PA-440 firewall
